# create custom .phtml

Tags: magento2, phtml

HI I want to ask if I create a custom template phtml file.
inside the coding
do I need to include below 2 tags?

```
<html></html> and <body></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to this tags are add

you can start
`<div>` or else any `<section>` or rest elements

Comment: Hi! thanks for your help, do you think you can help my another question? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326121/magento-custom-phtml-correct-way-to-insert-the-3rd-party-codecode

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you don't really need that tags in your custom phtml.

As phtml will be called in container and container is already placed in `<body>` tag.

You can use `<div>` if you want to add html in phtml file.